# Is it possible to revert a webpage saved as a PDF file back to the webpage?

Tags: pdf, webpage

If it is possible to save a webpage as a PDF file, is it possible then to revert this pdf back to the original webpage, or reveal the name of the URL?

Comment: I don't understand this question. What problem are you trying to solve? Please explain. What do you mean by "revert back to the original"? Do you want to get its HTML code? It seems to me like this is an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying so quick and sorry I wasn't clear with my question. Your reply has helped and guided my question though, in that, IS it possible to find the HTML code from the pdf? Maybe that is an easier and more direct question to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but do not expect the result to be identical to the original
HTML. You would be lucky for the result to be similar enough to the PDF page.
Depending on the complexity of the page, you might need to tweak it somewhat.

Googling for "pdf to html" will get about 445,000 results, many of them pointing
to online website (to be used with caution).

Here are some of them:

- Adobe Acrobat
- [PDF2HTML Online](https://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf-to-html/default.aspx)
- [Some PDF to HTML Converter](https://download.cnet.com/Some-PDF-To-Html-Converter/3000-2079_4-10836738.html)
- [pdf2htmlEX](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for getting back to me so quick. I will try the suggestions you gave me, starting with Adobe, as I agree with you, there is an awful lot to be wary of on the web. I am not expecting an exact replica of the webpage but just a basic would do. Thank you again.